# How use variable defined in one module in another module?

Tags: python

I want to pass a variable from **fileA.py** to **fileB.py** but i don't know how use (import) it in **fileB.py**.

I have this situation (frames folder and `file.A` are at same level)

```
frames
  |
  folder
    |
    fileB.py

fileA.py
```

In the `fileA.py`i have an image and i want to pass it in `fileB.py`

```
immagine= cv2.imread('image.jpg')
os.chdir("frames/folder")
subprocess.call(["python", "fileB.py", 'immagine'])
```

I think this works well but i don't know how import `immagine` in `fileB.py`.
Maybe i should to use:

```
from ..fileA.py from immagine
```

but not works and i have this error: **ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package**

I hope you can help me... i'm really new in python (like Ide i use pycharm and i use it to install modules - of course `fileB.py` and `fileA.py` aren't modules but normal python files)

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a subprocess? (Other than "I don't know how to import a package"?)

Comment: I think OP wants to pass image data as a parameter not just the string 'immagine'. I think it is a question about [shared memory](https://realpython.com/python-mmap/)

Comment: Yes i want to pass image data. Really should be a for loop and for each image (in a folder) i want to run fileB.py and pass image of iteration

Comment: don't even think about shared memory, or subprocesses. all you need is to figure out how python imports work. then you can just pass the numpy arrays to whatever function is in your other module.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two solutions, one using your `subprocess` call and another one with `import`:

**Easiest solution**

You can treat them as console command parameters and read them with `sys.argv`.

For example in `fileB.py`:

```py
from sys import argv
var = argv[1]

print(var)
```

Should output: `immagine`

**Arguably best solution**

Another way of doing it is to make both `fileA.py` and `fileB.py` part of the same module, even if `fileB.py` is a different submodule. For example:

```
mymodule
|    |  |
|    | fileA.py
|    |
|   folder
|      |
|     fileB.py
|  
__init__.py (this marks mymodule as a moduke)
```

And then in `fileB.py`:

```py
from mymodule.fileA import immagine
```

> **Take into account that you must run fileA with `python -m mymodule.fileA` for this to work**.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are unclear, so I'll just question all of them. You should not use a subprocess and you should not use shared memory, or any other hack.

You should simply define a function in `fileB.py`:

```py
# frames/folder/fileB.py

def do_something(im):
    # do something to im
    # return something
    return im.shape # for example

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # when running this script directly, do whatever you need to here
    # e.g. use a command line argument, read as an image file, call your function...
    ...
```

and then, in `fileA.py`, you do this:

```py
# fileA.py

from frames.folder.fileB import do_something
res = do_something(image)
print(res)
```

And that's all!

If you need the opposite, i.e. in the inner file, you want to call functions defined in the outer file, then you **do** need to make this a package, so you can use a relative import.

Comment: i want to pass image (immagine) from fileA.py  to fileB.py and in fileA.py i need to call fileB.py. I tried your code but now work :(

Comment: do you understand that you can't (should not) call entire files, but you can call functions in those files? "it didn't work" is not debuggable. at least tell me what happened.